# Passing a vector object to Matlab trough Mex routine

Tags: matlab, mex

I have an definition of a vector as typedef std::vector IpVec;
Ipvec ipts; //this is the object i Use.

Ipoint is a class which has the following variables:

```
float x, y;
float scale;
float orientation;
int laplacian;
float descriptor[64];
float dx, dy;
int clusterIndex;
```

How do I return ipts back to Matlab ?

Comment: Have you yet mastered the much simpler operation of returning a 1D vector of, say, floats from C/C++ to Matlab ?  If not, I suggest you do before tackling this problem directly.

Comment: I have done for returning of 1D vector of float to matlab. But I am stuck here.

Comment: Look at the documentation for returning structures from mex files. Try to return the member data of one lpoint class in a structure first and then work up to returning the vector.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example included with Matlab which you can open with this command:

```
edit([matlabroot '/extern/examples/mx/mxcreatestructarray.c']);
```

I think it covers everything you need to do.